Modes aren't enabled properly when visiting a buffer saved in a perspective (persp-mode.el)
I'm an emacs noob, forgive me for any incorrect terminology or missing some important details.
I'm using persp-mode.el, but perspective.el was susceptible to the same problem.
The problem is, after I load my saved perspectives, any buffer that I re-visit from switch-buffer doesn't seem to trigger all the minor modes that I have configured for the file. This is an example of an .el file buffer saved in a perspective:
Minor modes enabled in this buffer: Auto-Revert Auto-Save Diff-Hl
Display-Line-Numbers Eldoc Flycheck Font-Lock Hl-Todo Yas

And this is after I find-alternate-file on it:
Minor modes enabled in this buffer: Auto-Revert Auto-Save Company
Diff-Hl Display-Line-Numbers Eldoc Flycheck Font-Lock Hl-Todo Hs
Parinfer-Rust Yas

Also, even modes that are enabled are not really working correctly, for example diff-hl doesn't show anything (I guess that has to do with vc not working correctly either?..)
At the same time, if I use find-file, everything works just as it should.
Where should I look? Is it perspective/persp-mode problem or something else? I tried to look around for similar perspective bugs around, but wasn't lucky. I guess it's because half of the hooks enabling the modes aren't triggering; is there a way to trigger those forcefully in my situation without having to reload files one by one?

UPD: Here's an example of one of minor modes that don't get enabled automatically:
(use-package parinfer-rust-mode
  :hook ((emacs-lisp-mode
          clojure-mode
          scheme-mode
          lisp-mode
          racket-mode
          hy-mode) . parinfer-rust-mode)
  :init
  (setq parinfer-rust-auto-download t))

If I enable it explicitly in a buffer, it works.
Also, for the above example the major mode is set correctly:
The major mode is ELisp/d mode defined in elisp-mode.el:


UPD-2: Here's a more broad example, company is hooked to prog-mode which is also not triggering:
(use-package company
  :diminish
  :bind (("C-."   . #'company-capf)
         ("M-SPC" .  #'company-complete))
  :hook (prog-mode . company-mode)
  :config
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-irony))


UPD-3: As per @CroadLangshan suggestion, I've written a function:
(defun my-company-hook-fn ()
  (message "!!! Running my-company-hook-fn")
  (company-mode +1))

Turns out it does get called although I'm not sure for which buffer, as it happens during the daemon startup:
Turning on magit-auto-revert-mode...done
!!! Running my-company-hook-fn
Starting Emacs daemon.

Now I think it probably has to do with the fact I'm using emacs daemon?.. Because that hook, in theory, should be run as many times as I have .el buffers (3 or 4 in loaded perspective), but it does so only once.

Can you post an example of non-working configuration you're using to enable a minor mode?

@CroadLangshan sure thing, added an UPD in the question description.

Not sure what's wrong with that.  If you try debugging e.g. by defining a hook function that prints output (e.g. using message) and then calls the mode function (e.g. company-mode), does your hook function get called?

@CroadLangshan thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that and update the question with the results.

@CroadLangshan did that, maybe my problem has something to do I'm running emacs in daemon mode?..
